# JS in Safari on Mac window.location issues

Tags: javascript, macos, safari

I have a very basic search box on my website.  It's worked great on Windows in every major browser.  Works fine on iOS in Chrome and Safari.  On Safari, on a Mac specifically (latest Safari/latest Mac), it has an issue.  I had a client report it but I can also reproduce in Browserstack.

This is the most basic 'take a search term and redirect to a search page' code yet on Mac it just redirects to a bad URL.  What am I missing?

On Windows, the resulting URL is (according to the backend as far as the URL getting passed):
https://dev7.blah.com/search/ergo

On Mac, the resulting URL is:
https://dev7.blah.com/?

```
   $(document).on('keyup', '.searchKeyword', function(e){                                
        if(e.keyCode == 13) {
            var url = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname;   
            if(url.slice(-1) != "/") {
                url = url+"/";
            }   
            url = url+"search"; 
            var keyword = $(this).val();            
            if(keyword.trim() != '') {
                url = url+"/"+keyword;
            }            
            location.href = url;
        }
    });
```

EDIT: I removed jQuery completely and still getting the same result:

```
function doSearch(event) {    
    if(event.keyCode == 13) {        
        var url = getURL();         
        var keyword = document.getElementById('searchBox').value;            
        if(keyword.trim() != '') {
            url = url+"search/"+keyword;
        }            
        window.location.href = url;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could it be because the address does not exist? You might have to have an `ergo` folder or a mod_rewrite. Are you sure you don't want to just use a `GET` URL, or hashtag instead? Then you won't have to do a rewrite.

Comment: There is a route setup to take anything that is /search/ and clean the keyword they type in and take you to the search page.  That's not the issue or it wouldn't work on Windows either unless I'm missing your point?  I'm not using rewrite rules.  This is a route in a PHP router app (slim).

Comment: I'm not going to lie. I don't know anything about slim. https://github.com/slimphp/Slim

Comment: You were able to reproduce this issue on your machine? Can you add logs everywhere to see what's being passed? Sounds like it simply didn't make it to `if(keyword.trim() != '') {`, so if you couldn't reproduce yourself, maybe your user simply didn't write anything in the searchbox.

Comment: I remember some cases where safari expects `returns false` after the `location.href = url`. If that doesn't fix it, maybe `location.assign(url)` might?

Comment: 1) It's not an issue with
2) I can reproduce it on the server directly, but only in Safari on Mac (via Browserstack)
3) I will try the return false part.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Kielstra I realize I'm coming back to this almost a month later but I'm hitting a brick wall with this thing.  I straight up put location.assign('https://thesite.com/search/term') in there with a return false after and Chrome on Windows works fine but the page just refreshes with whatever page I am on with a ? at the end.  I even stepped through the code in Safari on a Mac (using Browserstack) and it builds the URL like it is supposed to.  But it's like Safari just completely ignores it.  I might lose my mind!  This is the most frustrating browser bug I've ever dealt with!